# fire OnItemClick on listview when button is clicked

Tags: android, listview, onclick, onitemclick

I have a ListView that contains button on each item.
I want that the item click will cause the OnItemClick event of the list to fire,
as that event contains more info (id,position) than the OnClick event of the button.

This is an important action on the list, that's why I need the button and don't want a regular item click will cause it to fire (I guess making the button focusable will do the trick).

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to make your own adapter for the list.In getView() method do your necessory requirements.

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, R.layout.list_item, strings) {
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View row;

if (null == convertView) {
row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
} else {
row = convertView;
}

Button bt1 = (Button) row.findViewById(android.R.id.bt1);
bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v){
       //you will get position and do necessary method 
       }
});

return row;
}
});
```

Comment: that works (as long I use final var for the position).
thanks.

Comment: which id do you want?What all items are there in your List item?

Comment: my problem is actually more complicated, as sometimes the position I get to the onClick is wrong. but that's another issue...

Comment: post your new issue. I will try to help you.

Comment: hm, i actually dont think this is the best approach. You are creating a new anonymous OnClickListener object for each row, which is not very efficient and will lead to more GC work. Please see my answer...

Answer (score 2):

Is the row clickable also? Depending on if the row is clickable I would probably do one of the following;

1. You could just set `clickable=false` on the button, and let the touch propergate up to the parent, namely the list view row the button is in, and `onItemClickListener` should then be notified for that row
2. You could set a tag ([View.setTag(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29)) on the button that reports the position on the row that the button resides in, and read this tag in an `onClickListener`
3. You could follow the answer suggested by freshDroid on this page but that would be inefficient as you are creating a new `OnClickListener` ever time a view is created / recycled which will cause extra GC work.

Comment: I worked like this. clickable=false on the button But it not propagate onItemClickListener. do this methode work for you?